A weird shell script file
I've encountered an unusual file, but I'm unable to comprehend its contents. What could be the reason behind this?
-----weird_sh.sh-----
#!/bin/echo 11 22
echo 33

$./weird_sh.sh aa
11 22 ./weird_sh.sh aa


Exactly what surprises you about it? You might look into how shebangs work.

Note that "explain this code" questions need to be very narrow and specific to be on-topic here (and moreover our scope is limited to practical questions; puzzles and brain teasers have a different Stack Exchange site). Also, bash isn't involved at all in the execution of this (since the shebang points to an executable that isn't bash) -- that's kind of the point. The line echo 33 is thus a red herring -- because running this script doesn't invoke a shell interpreter, nothing interprets that line as code (strictly, this file isn't a shell script at all).

There's a pretty good explanation of it here: How does the #! shebang work?. The second answer is the one that I think is most helpful to your question.

(correspondingly, the _sh extension and .sh in the filename are both arguably deliberate misdirections attempting to lead the reader away from accurate understanding).
